# is it possible to share a message when offline with linkedin api

Tags: php, linkedin-api

is it possible to store the id of a user who grants permission to accept the app and then post  a "share" when the user completes an action but they are not logged into linkedin? i have done this with facebook but currently struggling to get my head around the oauth/linked in libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, once the user has authorized your application, you can store the user's oauth tokens and use those to update LinkedIn via the API when a user trigers a share/update, etc.

The only trick is to cover yourself in the case that the user rejects your application's access rights; filter all responses from the LinkedIn API looking for an error indicating that the access token is no longer valid (you should be doing this filtering anyways for throttling issues).

Comment: for anyone else reading this further on serialize the access token when storing the db and unserialize when using  (in php that is)

Comment: Why would you need to serialize the token... it is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

LINKEDIN API has no proper documentation..as to how i can use it..sample code which is provided SKuS